# org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data, tomcat8, eof

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.0 for uploading files to the server and I'm getting this error :

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [/project] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException:
>   Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is
>   java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Unexpected
>   EOF read on the socket] with root cause
>
> java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:722)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:40)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1072)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:140)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:261)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:581)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:326)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:642)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:349)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_161]   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:881)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101) ~[na:1.8.0_161]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:572)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(MultipartStream.java:596)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.skipPreamble(MultipartStream.java:614)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:865)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.(FileUploadBase.java:845)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2869)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3216)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1137)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_161]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_161]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]

This is my frontend:

```
<form class="form"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
             <div class="book__row form__group ">
                <select id="dropdown-category" name="options" class="form__input" required>
                    <option value="0">Wählen Sie eine Kategorie aus</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="book__row form__group ">
                <select id="dropdown-subcategory" name="options" class="form__input" required>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form__group">
                <input type="text" class="form__input form__input--blue-border" placeholder="NAME" id="filename" required>
                <label for="title" class="form__label">NAME</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form__group">
                <textarea id="description" class="form__input form__input--blue-border " rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform"
                    required> BESCHREIBUNG
                                </textarea>

            </div>

            <div class="form__group input-file-container">
                <input class="input-file" id="fileStream" type="file" required>
                <label tabindex="0" for="my-file" class="input-file-trigger">Datei hochladen</label>
                <p class="file-return"></p>
            </div>


     <div class=" form__group input-file-container" id="addBinaryDoc">
                <input class="input-file"  type="submit">
                <label tabindex="0" for="form-btn" class="input-file-trigger">Dokument hinzufügen</label>
                <p class="file-return"></p>
            </div>

        </form>





 JS
   var data = new FormData();
    data.append("fileStream", file);
    data.append("metadata", new Blob([JSON.stringify(doc)], { type: "application/json" }));

    return $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
        url: '/my/path',
        data: data,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false


    });
```

BACKEND:       my controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "save",headers = "content-type=multipart/*", method = { RequestMethod.POST 
 }, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
 @ResponseBody
 public void saveDocument(@RequestParam("fileStream") MultipartFile   multipartFile, 
 @RequestPart(name = "metadata", required = false) @Valid Document uploadedDocument)
```

I added also a multipart resolver

```
 @Bean
  public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    MultipartResolver resolver = new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    return resolver;
  }

 @Bean
  MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
     factory.setMaxFileSize("5120MB");
     factory.setMaxRequestSize("5120MB");
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
 }
```

`application.properties`:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=5MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
```

Tomcat `context.xml`

```
  <Context allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" path="/">
    <Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="100000" />
   </context>
```

Tomcat `web.xml`

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Tomcat `servlet.xml`

```
  <Connector port="1050"
maxThreads="400"   minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionUploadTimeout="36000000" connectionTimeout="60000" disableUploadTimeout="false" 
/>
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: When exactly are you getting this error? How would one reproduce it?

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your comment :) Unfortunately I cannot track this. It happens regularly when I try to upload a file. Sometimes it happens the first time and then it is ok and sometimes happens in the middle.it is incomprehensibl.  I've read about this issue and some people say it might happen if you attempt to close the browser while uploading a file or if internet connection is bad. This is not my case. I'm really helpless.